# Segmentation fault on pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
    int count,i,j;
    int* val;
    scanf("%d",count);
    val = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
    if(NULL == val){
        printf("\n memory is NULl \n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        scanf("%d",val[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=val[i];j++){
            if((j%3) == 0){
                printf("Fizz\n");
            }
            else if((j%5) == 0){
                printf("Buzz\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("%d\n",j);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O/P :

```
2
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: So we have to guess where the segfault happen?

Comment: It would be nice to have some more content than just a headline and a bunch of code. What have you done in terms of debugging? At which address does the segfault occur? Which line of code does that address correspond to? Etc.

Comment: Btw, in C you don't need (and shouldn't) cast the result of the `malloc()`. So, you can remove that `(int*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `scanf("%d",count)` to `scanf("%d",&count)`.

Also change

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    scanf("%d",val[i]);
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    scanf("%d", &val[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",count);
```

There is no & in scanf. It should be

```
scanf("%d",&count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

> "scanf("%d",count);" with "scanf("%d",&count);"

and

> "scanf("%d",val[i]);" with "scanf("%d",&val[i]);"